# A linker error of Boost.Python in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, boost

My english is very poor, so I appreciate if you try to understand my question.

---

I have Python3.3 , Boost 1.50.0 and visual studio 2008 installed, and all of them work fine.

Now **I want to embed python 2.7.6 in C++ by using Boost Python library,so I downloaded Portable Python 2.7.6.1** ( from portablepython.com/).
And I downloaded Boost lib. 1.50.0 again, extract them into another path, compiled them by following the building tutorial.

Everything seem alright, but when I tried to compile my code, I got a linker error.

```
Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'python32.lib'
```

**I have no idea why it was not 'python27.lib'**
I am confused, because I never install Python3.2, and I have modified user-config.jam to make sure that all paths has been redirect to my Portable Python(2.7) folders,and the new Boost library were successfully built without error.

I have been trying to solve the problem for a few weeks, using lots of ways , but it still doesn't work

---

All the things I have done are :

1. Download **Boost C++ library** (boost_1_50_0.7z from www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_50_0.html)
2. Extract them into my boost root path(**D:\Proj\ThirdPartyLib\boost_1_50_0**)
3. Download **Portable Python 2.7.6.1** ( from portablepython.com/wiki/PortablePython2.7.6.1/ )
4. Extract them into **D:\Py27Test**
5. Modify `user-config.jam`, add the following text and save it into D:\Proj\ThirdPartyLib\boost_1_50_0\
       `using python : 2.7 : "D:\Py27Test\App" : "D:\Py27Test\App\include" : "D:\Py27Test\App\libs" :  ;`
6. Execute Visual Studio Command Prompt (x86)

   1. `cd /D D:\Proj\ThirdPartyLib\boost_1_50_0`
   2. `bootstrap`
   3. `bjam --toolset=msvc-9.0 --python=2.7 --user-config=D:\Proj\ThirdPartyLib\boost_1_50_0\user-config.jam --debug-configuration`
          the debug infomations are:
          `notice: [python-cfg] Configuring python...`
          `notice: [python-cfg]   user-specified version: "2.7"`
          `notice: [python-cfg] Checking interpreter command "python"...`
          `notice: [python-cfg] running command 'DIR /-C /A:S "D:\Py27Test\App\python.exe" 2>&1'`
          `notice: [python-cfg] running command '"python" -c "from sys import *; print('version=%d.%d\nplatform=%s\nprefix=%s\nexec_prefix=%s\nexecutable=%s' % (version_info[0],version_info[1],platform,prefix,exec_prefix,executable))" 2>&1'`
          `notice: [python-cfg] ...requested configuration matched!`
          `notice: [python-cfg] Details of this Python configuration:`
          `notice: [python-cfg]   interpreter command: "python"`
          `notice: [python-cfg]   include path: "D:\Py27Test\App\include"`
          `notice: [python-cfg]   library path: "D:\Py27Test\App\libs"`
          `notice: [python-cfg]   DLL search path: "D:\Py27Test\App"`
7. Execute Visual Studio 2008

   1. Add **D:\Proj\ThirdPartyLib\boost_1_50_0** to compiler include paths
   2. Add **D:\Proj\ThirdPartyLib\boost_1_50_0\stage\lib** to linker library paths
8. create a testing code:

> ```
> #define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
> #include <boost/python.hpp>
> #include <iostream>
>
> int main(int argc, char** argv) {
>      return 0;
> }
> ```

9. Complie the code and I would get a linker error (**Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'python32.lib'**)

---

Did I miss something?

Or does anyone has any idea to solve this problem?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Thanks for your notice. Yes I did, but I don't know where to find the .lib file.  I have tried to rename Python27.lib to Python32.lib, but it didn't work (crashed at run-time).

And I searched about the name "Python32.lib", but I could not find useful informations about 32-bit library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this problem.

1. Add D:\Py27Test\App\include to compiler include paths
2. Add D:\Py27Test\App\libs to linker library paths

Seems like if I don't include Python.h, it will link to a default library file.
So after I added those paths, it works now.